# SpringBoot + OAuth2 without Zuul

Tags: angularjs, oauth-2.0, spring-boot, netflix-zuul

i'm currently building an SpringBoot Application consisting of three main parts:

1. Frontend Server (For the Frontend Application I'm using AngularJS)
2. Authentication Server (I'm using OAuth2 for authentication)
3. Resource Server (Provides RESTServices for the Frontend)

I already found a very useful [tutorial](https://spring.io/blog/2015/02/03/sso-with-oauth2-angular-js-and-spring-security-part-v), which works fine for me. But I'm wondering if there is a way to omit the Zuul Proxy on the Frontend? I want to directly call the resource endpoint 'localhost:9000/resource' out of my frontend angularJS application.

I already added a CORSFilter to my Resource Server (for this step i used this [tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/))

But when I send the request out of my AngularJS application the resource server responds with an HTTP 401 error, although i'm already authenticated to the Authentication Server.

I already tried to analyse the communication between the Browser and the Server, that provides the RESTService, with Fiddler. By doing this, I found out, that my AngularJS application does not send any Session IDs in the Request Header.

Do you have any idea, where i could continue searching for an solution to my problem?

Kind regards,
Florian